# Reading a txt file and assign variable sign batch

Tags: batch-file

Good morning Gurus out there.
I have a file called ABC.txt in which there are some lines :

```
001 09.10.2017  A   "\\server\a.txt"
...
...
030 10.10.2017  D   "\\server\b.txt"
```

on each there are 4 values separated by TAB.

Is it possible with batch, read the Latest line of this file
create 4 variables and assigned the value read in that line?

i.e.

```
a=030
b=10.10.2017
c=D
e="\\server\b.txt"
```

I am trying with for /f but I cannot reach the goal.
thanks in advance

Comment: Show your attempt! Why do you need there variables, why not just using the `for /F` variable references?

Comment: FOR /F "tokens=* delims= " %%i in (ABC.txt) do (
echo var_i=%%i
) With this I am able to read inside the file, but: a) I am reading all the lines, not just the latest, and b) everytime I overwrite the same variable. I need to have variables because later on there are some scripts running using those variables.

Comment: Please include your code in the question rather than as a comment... thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for loop` will assign all the variables for each line, *overwriting the last*, until it reaches then end of file. When it does that the variables will contain only the data retrieved from that last line.

*Don't worry, it may seem inefficient but will do so really quickly.*

```bat
@Echo Off

If Not Exist "ABC.txt" Exit/B

For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1-4 Delims= " %%A In ("ABC.txt") Do (
    Set "_a=%%A"
    Set "_b=%%B"
    Set "_c=%%C"
    Set "_d=%%D"
)

Echo %%_a%% = %_a%
Echo %%_b%% = %_b%
Echo %%_c%% = %_c%
Echo %%_d%% = %_d%

Pause
```

Where *"UseBackQ Tokens=1-4 Delims=<kbd>TAB</kbd>"*

**Edit**

Based upon Mr. Benham's comment; Because the default delimiters in a `For` loop are <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and your example data does not indicate any spaces, you could use the following, missing out the `Delims` statement, instead:

```bat
@Echo Off

If Not Exist "ABC.txt" Exit/B

For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1-3*" %%A In ("ABC.txt") Do (
    Set "_a=%%A"
    Set "_b=%%B"
    Set "_c=%%C"
    Set "_d=%%D"
)

Echo %%_a%% = %_a%
Echo %%_b%% = %_b%
Echo %%_c%% = %_c%
Echo %%_d%% = %_d%

Pause
```

*Where `%%D` will be the value of the remainder of the line beyond the third delimiter*.

Comment: With the data that the OP has shown, it is unlikely that there are any spaces in the first 3 values. So the OP can probably use `"UseBackQ tokens=1-3*"` and not worry about embedding a [TAB] within the script.

Comment: Understood and accepted; however for a learner it is easier to visualise four tokens with four results, _(kind of a walk before you can run situation)_.